# Bluetooth on Aspire 4720Z

Tags: 12.10, bluetooth

How do I make ubuntu recognize the bluetooth adapter in my computer, I have Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: We need more info about what hardware you are using, what type of bluetooth adapter will be used and anything else that can help us give you an answer. As it stands, it is very hard to post an answer with the amount of information provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known bug with Linux and the Bluetooth adapter used in Acer computers, which is HonHai/Foxconn. Please have a look at this bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/898826

As far as I know, it is said that a fix was released some time ago. However, my personal experience is that it still doesn't work on Acer computers. So I don't think you can make your Bluetooth work until a proper bug fix is released, or until you fix this bug, if you're able to :) If you do, please let the rest of us know.

Comment: I looked at that page but I couldn't find a fix, is there a fix that has been made but not released?

Comment: As I wrote, some people say their problem was solved in linux kernel 3.5, but I have an Acer and my Bluetooth still isn't working. So I can't help you any further, unfortunately.